# fb:visible-to-connection and fb:else shows as if both are true

Tags: facebook, fbml

I've been testing out FBML and I've come across a problem. 
When I use the following code it shows both results,

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>
First
<fb:else>
Second
</fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
```

The output is "FirstSecond"

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [dropped support for static FBML](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462) in back in March.

If you are creating a Page tab application, you need to use Iframes (as mentioned in the post) and utilize the Graph API.   [Here is a great tutorial](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php) on how you can show content to Likers vs. Non-likers in your Iframed app.